# What is the difference between in-context learning and few-shot prompting?

Tags: llm, prompt-design, terminology

In-context learning is a prompt engineering technique where natural-language demonstrations are provided as part of the prompt ([source](https://www.hopsworks.ai/dictionary/in-context-learning-icl)).

Few-shot prompting is about providing a few examples in the prompt ([source](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-are-zero-shot-prompting-and-few-shot-prompting/)).

These seem like the same concept to me. What is the difference between in-context learning and few-shot prompting?

Is few-shot prompting a subset of in-context learning, or are they just different names for the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

In-context learning doesn't imply one only give a few examples, unlike few-shot prompting. That's the only difference I can see, and many people assume that in-context learning uses only a few examples anyway, e.g. see [A Survey on In-context Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.00234.pdf):

> Following the paper of GPT-3 (Brown et al., 2020), we provide a definition of in-context learning: Incontext learning is a paradigm that allows language models to learn tasks given only a few examples in the form of demonstration.

By the way, the same paper explains the difference between few-shot learning and in-context learning:

> Few-shot learning is a general machine learning approach that uses parameter adaptation to learn the best model parameters for the
> task with a limited number of supervised examples (Wang and Yao, 2019). In contrast, ICL does
> not require parameter updates and is directly performed on pretrained LLMs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Per the second half on few-shot learning, note that few-shot learning is different than few-shot prompting

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer yes indeed, different